# Starting launcher and moving to default homescreen

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'd like to start a specific launcher (set by the user), which is working fine with the code below. However, the launcher isn't moving to the user's "default" screen (e.g. the leftmost screen), but rather to the one where the user last left off. Is there a way to tell the launcher to move to the user's default screen upon opening? I've tried `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`.

```
 Intent home = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
 home.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
 home.setClassName(launcherPackage, launcherActivity);
 startActivity(home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by sending the above-mentioned `Intent` *twice* (once to actually show the homescreen, and the second time to move the homescreen back to the default desktop).